# Can i Access state from Component Did Mount

Tags: reactjs

First i am getting data through axios and setting my state inside component Did Mount.Then i want to get my image but for that purpose i need to access the info from my state which I have previously set but when i am logging my info the answer is undefined. Is there any way that in component did Mount I set my state and then get data from the state inside component did mount.

```
   state = {
        info: [],
        getImage: null
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:4000/home/profile/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then(res => {
                const info = res.data;
                this.setState({ info });
            })
            .catch(err => console.log("Some problem", err));

        console.log("personimage", this.state.info);

        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:4000/home/${this.state.info.personImage}/`, {
                responseType: "arraybuffer"
            })
            .then(response => {
                let image = btoa(
                    new Uint8Array(response.data).reduce(
                        (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
                        ""
                    )
                );
```

Comment: First check promise is getting resolved because if its resolved then res.data is assigned to info and info assigns to state.

Comment: yes, from my first axios my state is set and i can get data from state in my render method.But i cannot get data from state in component did mount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is *asynchronous*.  You can read about it [in the docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

To get something to happen right after `setState` fires and state changes, you can pass a callback, like this:

```
 this.setState({ info }, () => console.log(this.state.info);
```